What is the landowner liability for homeless encampments on property?
Municipalities are increasingly dealing with homeless people encamped in public spaces.  This creates difficulties for the city, since many residents who use and pay (via their tax $) to upkeep the public space do not wish to share with homeless who may bring concomitant sanitation issues, etc.  However, private landowners may not be opposed to some quantity of encampments on vacant property, even knowing the associated issues that will accompany such an encampment.  Whereas creating a full-fledged shelter is a significant investment,  landowners may be more inclined to simply "allow" homeless on their property if such allowance was ~0 effort.  However, allowing this activity on one's property may come with significant liability.  Landowners are careful about being "held responsible" for issues on their property (e.g. if someone slips and falls).
Do landowners generally expose themselves to public-use liability if they don't actively enforce trespassing statutes against homeless encampments on their property?  Are there factors that might limit or increase a landowner's exposure to liability?  Are there avenues by which a landowner might limit their liability when homeless use a vacant property, aside from actively evicting them?

Try https://www.glsp.org/

I don't see why their liability would depend on whether the people on their land are homeless or not.

@Barmar I suppose that it doesn't strictly matter that one is homeless, but I suspect that the homed are less likely to be camping out on a vacant lot.  So, while my question technically applies to the general populace, I think that the 99.9 percentile case would involve the homeless.

@Barmar perhaps the distinction you are making is whether the premises in question are typically used by the general public.  Is this an important distinction?

Probably. I just googled "do campgrounds have to be licensed", and it's generally required. It's possible that allowing people to set up encampments on your property would be viewed as operating a campground, even if it's free.

@Barmar "Landlord is ignorant of the situation" would be an interesting answer to the "Are there avenues bu which...?" part of the question.  I'll rephrase that slightly to make this more clear.  Thanks for the advice.

Does "allow" mean the landowner gives explicit permission for encampments on their property? And is that general permission, or individual?

@WeatherVane this is a good point.  Does "giving explicit permission" vs "actively encouraging" vs "turning a blind eye" vs "trying to remove but held up by legal paperwork" make a difference with respect to exposure to legal liability?  If so, then I would upvote an answer that expounded upon this.

new-hampshire
New Hampshire may be an outlier among U.S. states, as it has a mechanism to place privately owned land in contiguous areas of 10 acres or more into a status called "Current Use" (pdf).
Current Use land must be natural, unimproved land (or farmland) that must remain natural while it has that status, with no logging or mining allowed by the landowner or by anyone else. Land in Current Use status is taxed by the local property taxing authority at a small fraction of the tax rate on improved land. In exchange for this low tax rate, the landowner grants license to the public to enter the land and use it for any recreational purpose, including camping. Posting of No Trespass signs is not allowed on Current Use land.
In addition, in recognition of New Hampshire's hunting and fishing tradition, any land, public or private, that is not posted with No Hunting, No Trespassing or similar prohibitive signs may be entered by anyone licensed and equipped to hunt or fish in season, and this is not considered trespass.
Whether land is in Current Use status or not, and whether it is posted or not, landowners in New Hampshire have strong protection under state law from liability for recreational use of their land, including camping, with or without their knowledge.
New Hampshire Fish and Game publishes a booklet on landowner liability and duty of care under state law. It is reproduced here:

Landowner Liability
New Hampshire Landowner Liability and Duty of Care
Laws. Your Rights and Responsibilities Outdoor Recreation on Private
Land: What Landowners Need to Know
This information applies to landowners, land lessee, easement holders,
land occupants, and land managers.
If someone comes onto my land and gets hurt, am I liable?
No, except in a few rare cases. The Landowner Liability Law (RSA
508:14) and Duty of Care Law (RSA 212:34) protect landowners from
liability when someone gets hurt on their property.
If someone uses your land for outdoor recreational activities and they
get hurt on your property, you assume no responsibility or incur no
liability. You are protected whether or not you give permission to use
the land, and whether or not you sign your land as “No Trespassing”.
What does the landowner liability law NOT protect?
There are a few situations where you are not protected. These include
charging a fee for entering the property to recreate, maliciously
failing to warn against a dangerous condition, and intentionally
hurting the recreational user.
Is the recreational user responsible for their own risk?
Yes, RSA 212:34 clearly states that “outdoor recreational activities
may be hazardous”. Therefore participants of outdoor recreation
activities must assume the inherent risk and dangers they may face
including variations in terrain on trails and paths such as rocks,
stumps, equipment not in use, other objects, other people, and in snow
or ice conditions.
Useful Definitions taken from RSA 212:34, Duty of Care Law
"Charge" means a payment or fee paid by a person to the landowner for
entry upon, or use of the premises, for outdoor recreational activity.
"Landowner" means an owner, lessee, holder of an easement, occupant of
the premises, or person managing, controlling, or overseeing the
premises on behalf of such owner, lessee, holder of an easement, or
occupant of the premises.
"Outdoor recreational activity" means outdoor recreational pursuits
including, but not limited to, hunting, fishing, trapping, camping,
horseback riding, bicycling, water sports, winter sports, snowmobiling
as defined in RSA 215-C:1, XV, operating an OHRV as defined in RSA
215-A:1, V, hiking, ice and rock climbing or bouldering, or
sightseeing upon or removing fuel wood from the premises.
"Premises'' means the land owned, managed, controlled, or overseen by
the landowner upon which the outdoor recreational activity subject to
this section occurs
If there is something dangerous on my property and I guard the area
off, post signs, or verbally tell a recreational user about it, am I
assuming liability?
No, any warning given by a landowner, whether oral, sign, guard, or
other means, shall not be the basis of liability for a claim that the
warning was inadequate or insufficient. The exception is if the
landowner maliciously fails to warn against the dangerous condition.
Is it still possible for me to get sued in spite of the landowner
liability law?
Yes, however, the law includes a provision that makes the claimant
responsible for all court fees that may be a deterrent for bringing
the lawsuit. Also, the few cases that have been brought to court have
all been in favor of the landowner not owing any liability.
If I am found not liable in a court of law, do I have to cover my
court costs?
No. If the court finds that there is no reasonable basis for bringing
a claim against the landowner, the claimant will be ordered to pay for
reasonable attorney’s fees and costs incurred by the landowner in
defending against the action.
Practical Advice:
While the Landowner Liability and Duty of Care Laws protect
landowners, use common sense when dealing with unwanted recreation
users on your land.  If you do not want a certain type of recreation
use on your land, clearly sign and mark the restriction so that it is
visible day and night and at all times of the year. Reach out to local
recreation groups and inform them of your decision to change allowable
uses on the land.
The information contained in this brochure is only a summary. Please
consult a lawyer for more detailed information and advice specific to
your situation.
NH Rev Stat § 508:14
NH Rev Stat § 212:34

Under New Hampshire law, camping on one place for more than 14 days within any 28-day period is considered to be taking up residence, which is unlawful. Private landowners who become aware of long-term camping on their land can request a No Trespass order be issued to the offender by local police.
Based on New Hampshire news reports that I've read, if police have been called to have a camper "trespassed" from their land (an awful term, though it is in common use), the police generally give well-behaved campers who appear to be homeless two weeks to gather their things and go somewhere else before issuing the no trespass order. Campers who fail to leave or who return before the order expires are arrested.

A very "live free or die" law.
